# Emulators are always started with "Process system isn't repsonding"

Tags: android, android-emulator

Since a few days I can't start the emulator anymore.

I am always getting "Process system isn't responding". I can't click anything.

[image]

Can anyone help? I have tried to recreate the emulator, tried to restart everything. No success. Always the same.

**Android Studio Version:**

Android Studio 2.2.3

Build #AI-145.3537739, built on December 2, 2016

JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Here are my logs and settings:

**Android Studio Log:**

D:\Android_SDK\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd

Nexus_5X_Nougat_API_24

Hax is enabled

Hax ram_size 0x40000000

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554

emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554

**Emulator Setting:**
[image]

**This is the log output with the System ANR:**

```
ANR in com.android.systemui
   PID: 1719
   Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) }
   Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
   CPU usage from 64923ms to 0ms ago (2017-02-19 15:25:40.738 to 2017-02-19 15:26:46.029):
     2.7% 1489/system_server: 0.6% user + 2% kernel / faults: 8564 minor 33 major
     1% 1252/adbd: 0% user + 1% kernel / faults: 5077 minor
     0.5% 1248/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 77 minor
     0.4% 1719/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 5393 minor 48 major
     0.2% 11/migration/1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
     0.2% 1872/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 2223 minor 15 major
     0.2% 1277/rild: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 11 minor
     0.1% 1322/bootanimation: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
     0% 4/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1959/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1086 minor 1 major
     0% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 650/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1184/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1204/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 449 minor
     0% 1247/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 7/migration/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1194/jbd2/vdc-8: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1196/logd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 45 minor
     0% 1244/healthd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
     0% 1256/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
     0% 1671/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 112 minor
   3% TOTAL: 0.4% user + 2.4% kernel + 0.1% iowait + 0% softirq
   CPU usage from 123661ms to 123661ms ago (1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 to 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000) with 0% awake:
   0% TOTAL: 0% user + 0% kernel
```

Comment: Does no one have this problem?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Seems this was a problem of the  video driver or emulator. After update it has worked again. But I don't know what exactly solved the problem.

So try to update your video card driver if an update is available and check if Android Studio has an update for the emulator.

A workaround is to disable the hardware acceleration in the emulator setting.